# CD into multiple unknown directories 1 at a time and create sub directories

Tags: arrays, batch-file

I am writing a bat that will run nightly that moves multiple directories into new directories based on 1st part of directory name which I have done. 
original folders are created by lot # date and time and iteration # of lot.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=_" %%d in ('dir /b /ad *') do mkdir G:\folder1\folder2\working\%%d
```

from `A1I00K161_170328_091931_001` I create `A1I00K161`
Then I need to find a way to go into those new folders and create 5 additional folders.
My bat now needs to go into each of these new directories without me having to manually tell it the new directory name. Assuming `dir /b` to list new directories, but I cannot find a way to turn them into variables that my bat can use.

Comment: Before you ask any questions, take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE].

Comment: Did you even take a few seconds to [search some of the existing answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5Diterate+directories)?

Comment: `pushd G:\folder1\folder2\working\%%d`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **FOR** loop can be used the command

```
pushd "G:\folder1\folder2\working\%%d"
```

to push current directory path on stack and change into the just created directory.
Then do something in this directory like creating five subdirectories.

Last the command

```
popd
```

must be used in the **FOR** loop to pop previous current directory from stack and make this directory again the current directory.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=_" %%d in ('dir /b /ad *') do (
    mkdir "G:\folder1\folder2\working\%%d"
    pushd "G:\folder1\folder2\working\%%d"
    rem Other commands like five times MKDIR or MD with just directory name.
    popd
)
```

But there is absolutely no need to change the current directory at all. The best batch files using fixed directory paths work independent on what is the current directory on starting the batch file.

For example this batch code could be used if the source directory is `C:\Temp\Test`:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "BaseTarget=G:\folder1\folder2\working"
for /D %%D in ("C:\Temp\Test\*") do (
    for /F "delims=_" %%I in ("%%~nxD") do (
        mkdir "%BaseTarget%\%%I\First Subfolder"
        mkdir "%BaseTarget%\%%I\Second Subfolder"
        mkdir "%BaseTarget%\%%I\Third Subfolder"
        mkdir "%BaseTarget%\%%I\Fourth Subfolder"
        mkdir "%BaseTarget%\%%I\Fifth Subfolder"
    )
)
endlocal
```

The command **FOR** with option `/D` searches in specified directory for non hidden subdirectories matching the pattern `*` and assigns the name of each found subdirectory with full path to loop variable `D`.

The inner **FOR** splits the name of the folder without path up into substrings (tokens) using the specified delimiter being the underscore and assigns by default only the first string to specified loop variable `I` which is all needed for this task.

The command **MKDIR** creates an entire directory tree with command extensions enabled as by default and here additionally explicitly enabled.

But a different batch file code is needed if the source directory is identical to base target directory like `G:\folder1\folder2\working`:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "BaseFolder=G:\folder1\folder2\working"
for /F "delims=_" %%I in ('dir "%BaseFolder%\*" /AD /B /ON 2^>nul') do (
    mkdir "%BaseFolder%\%%I\First Subfolder"
    mkdir "%BaseFolder%\%%I\Second Subfolder"
    mkdir "%BaseFolder%\%%I\Third Subfolder"
    mkdir "%BaseFolder%\%%I\Fourth Subfolder"
    mkdir "%BaseFolder%\%%I\Fifth Subfolder"
)
endlocal
```

On execution of this batch file **FOR** executes the command line

```
dir "G:\folder1\folder2\working\*" /AD /B /ON 2>nul
```

with using a separate command process started in background with `cmd.exe /C` and captures everything output to handle **STDOUT** of this command process for later processing. **DIR** outputs just all names of subdirectories in specified directory including the hidden subdirectories without path.

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

The important difference to batch code with `for /D` is the captured list of directory names processed by **FOR**. So even on creating additional directories, renaming or deleting already existing directories, the list of directories processed by **FOR** does not change anymore while running the commands in the command block. Usage of `for /D` on a directory of which directory entries change during execution can result often in processing some directories multiple times or skip directories.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `mkdir /?` or `md /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`